# Error while compiling Solidity code via py-solc

Tags: solc, compilation

I am getting the following error while attempting to compile Solidity code via `py-solc`. Is it due to a new update of `py-solc`? how can I fix it?

```py
>>> from . import views
  File "/home/manzik/Desktop/Ethereum Voting/voting/home/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    import commission.views as comm
  File "/home/manzik/Desktop/Ethereum Voting/voting/commission/views.py", line 164, in <module>
    compiled_sol = compile_source(contract_source_code)
  File "/home/manzik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/solc/main.py", line 108, in compile_source
    stdoutdata, stderrdata, command, proc = solc_wrapper(**compiler_kwargs)
  File "/home/manzik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/solc/utils/string.py", line 85, in inner
    return force_obj_to_text(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/manzik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/solc/wrapper.py", line 169, in solc_wrapper
    stderr_data=stderrdata,
solc.exceptions.SolcError: An error occurred during execution
> command: `solc --combined-json abi,asm,ast,bin,bin-runtime,clone-bin,devdoc,interface,opcodes,userdoc`
> return code: `1`
> stderr:

> stdout:
Invalid option to --combined-json: clone-bin
```

Answer (score 1):

`py-solc` [has been deprecated](https://github.com/ethereum/py-solc/pull/65#issuecomment-448729689) and does not support `solc` versions `^0.5.0`. The error you have posted is consistent with attempting to compile using a `0.5.x` version.

I have forked the project as `py-solc-x` and continue to maintain it. You can install it via pip:

`pip install py-solc-x`

Keep in mind this is no longer an official release from the Ethereum snake charmers. I encourage you to review the code on [Github](https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/py-solc-x) before using it.

Answer (score 0):

try python3 -m solc.install v0.4.25